# why does it keep saying permision denied in my ubuntu virtual box machine when I am the only one using it

Tags: 22.10

I am trying to run geant4 on my ubuntu virtual machine however it does not want to cooperate. everything I do goes wrong. the Cmake compilation doesn't work even when I open the terminal from the file itself it says the directory doesn't have so and so file when the directory does have so and so file. the when I want to create a folder using the mkdir command it says permission denied when I am the one who created the virtual machine who do I need to get permission from. I am not familiar with ubuntu or linux in general, I have always been a windows user and this is my first exposure to linux. please I need someone to help me through this every tutorial I use seems the get me entangled deeper into this web of confusion.

Comment: Where are you trying to create a new directory? Can you paste the output along with the Ubuntu version you're using?

Comment: Some apps and commands require you to be root.